# creating an iam role for a specific domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-route53

How can I create a role where an EC2 instance has full access to route53 except a specific domain? I have been looking at the condition and can't figure out how to give full access except a specific domain

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NotResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notresource.html) to "blacklist" a specific domain.